# Problems reading a whole line from textfile

Tags: excel, vba, file

I have a program that reads lines of text (some 3000-4000 lines) from a textfile (saved with UTF from Notes). Each line consists of about 300-900 characters. I used this function:

```
    Function loadVerbs2(fullPathName As String) As String()
    Dim strings(0 To 5000) As String
    Dim my_file As Integer
    Dim text_line As String
    Dim stringNr As Integer
    my_file = FreeFile()
    Open fullPathName For Input As my_file
    stringNr = 0
    While Not EOF(my_file)
        Line Input #my_file, text_line
'Cut preceding "
        While ((Asc(Left$(text_line, 1)) < Asc("a")) Or (Asc(Left$(text_line, 1)) > Asc("z")))
            text_line = Mid$(text_line, 2)
        Wend
' Cut ending " and ,
        While ((Right$(text_line, 1) = Chr$(34)) Or (Right$(text_line, 1) = ","))
            text_line = Left$(text_line, Len(text_line) - 1)
        Wend
        strings(stringNr) = latinCharacter(text_line)
        stringNr = stringNr + 1
    Wend
    Close #my_file
    loadVerbs2 = strings
End Function
```

For some reason the function doesn't read the whole line, but cut them.
So I changed it to this:

```
Function loadVerbs(fullPathName As String) As String()
    Dim strings(0 To 5000) As String
    Dim text_line As String
    Dim stringNr As Integer
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim ts As TextStream
    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(fullPathName)
        Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
            text_line = ts.ReadLine
'Cut preceding "
            While ((Asc(Left$(text_line, 1)) < Asc("a")) Or (Asc(Left$(text_line, 1)) > Asc("z")))
                text_line = Mid$(text_line, 2)
            Wend
' Cut ending " and ,
            While ((Right$(text_line, 1) = Chr$(34)) Or (Right$(text_line, 1) = ","))
                text_line = Left$(text_line, Len(text_line) - 1)
            Wend
            strings(stringNr) = latinCharacter(text_line)
            stringNr = stringNr + 1
        Loop
    ts.Close
    loadVerbs = strings
End Function
```

But with the same result. There are some characters like this in the text: á í é ó à ò ì è â û î ñ ç which makes it neceserry for this "latinCharacter" function to convert them so I can put them on a spreadsheet. But these characters does not stop the ReadLine or Line Input from reading the entire line.
Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem solved! The easy answer is that there wasn't any problem. When you run the Microsoft Visual Basic for Application debugger and show the local variables window the debugger doesn't show the whole length of the strings. So the program works but it looks like it doesn't in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use an ADO Stream. One advantage is the possibility to set the right charset.
[For infos to ADO Stream look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/stream-object-ado?view=sql-server-ver15)

Here is a demo for you with the relevant parameters for text imports and what they stand for:

```
Sub AdoStreamDemo()

Dim importPath As String
Dim importFileName As String
Dim objStream As Object
Dim lineOfTextFile As String

  
  importPath = "D:\Your Folder\" 'Don't forget the bakslash (\) at the end
  importFileName = "Your File.xxx" 'Filename with extension
  
  'Initialise ADO Stream
  Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  objStream.Charset = "utf-8" 'default is Unicode
  objStream.Type = 2 '2 = Text, 1 = Binary
  objStream.LineSeparator = -1 '-1 = adCrLf (default), 13 = adCr, 10 = adLf
  objStream.Open 'Opens the stream
  objStream.LoadFromFile importPath & importFileName 'Path with backslash (\) at the end and filename
  
  Do Until objStream.EOS 'EOS = End Of Stream
    lineOfTextFile = objStream.ReadText(-2) '-2 = one row, -1 = all
    'Do here what you want to do with every line of text from the file
    Debug.Print lineOfTextFile
  'Next line
  Loop
  
  objStream.Close 'Closes the stream
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the effort but I get a:
Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)
Wrong parameter. (or however you translate it)
in this line:
lineOfTextFile = objStream.ReadText(-2) '-2 = one row, -1 = all
I never used ADO before. I tried to add the references:
Microsoft ADO Ext. 2.8 for DDL and Security
Microsoft ADO Ext. 6.0 for DDL and Security
But still the same error. Is there another reference/library one should add when using ADO?

Comment: I found this:
To reference ADO from Microsoft Visual Basic. Select Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library from the list. Verify that at least the following libraries are also selected:
Visual Basic for Applications,
Visual Basic runtime objects and procedures,
Visual Basic objects and procedures,
OLE Automation.
But I can't find all these libraries. I run Excel2010 on Windows10

Comment: The example is programmed with late binding. References only have to be set for early binding. https://peltiertech.com/Excel/EarlyLateBinding.html I'll check tomorrow to see if it causes the same error in Excel 2010 for me.

Comment: Only as information because your problem is solved. My example for ADO Stream works for me with Windows 7 and Excel 2010 as it should. I have no idea why you get the error mesage when you have entered a valid path and filename.